# Baker missed an endorsement

Tags: baker, kiln

Two times in a row baker missed an endorsement, I look for why. Below logs, anyone can explain me what does it mean?

```
Feb 23 02:16:32 kiln-baker[1854]: Feb 23 02:16:32 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge: No slot found at level 836230 (max_priority = 64)
Feb 23 02:17:31 kiln-baker[1854]: Feb 23 02:17:31 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge: No slot found at level 836231 (max_priority = 64)
Feb 23 02:18:34 kiln-baker[1854]: Feb 23 02:18:34 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge: No slot found at level 836232 (max_priority = 64)
Feb 23 02:19:30 kiln-baker[1854]: Feb 23 02:19:30 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge: No slot found at level 836233 (max_priority = 64)
Feb 23 02:20:32 kiln-baker[1854]: Feb 23 02:20:32 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge: No slot found at level 836234 (max_priority = 64)
Feb 23 02:21:35 kiln-baker[1854]: Feb 23 02:21:35 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge: No slot found at level 836235 (max_priority = 64)
Feb 23 02:22:33 kiln-baker[1854]: Feb 23 02:22:33 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge: No slot found at level 836236 (max_priority = 64)
Feb 23 02:23:36 kiln-baker[1854]: Feb 23 02:23:36 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge: No slot found at level 836237 (max_priority = 64)
Feb 23 02:24:38 kiln-baker[1854]: Feb 23 02:24:38 - 005-PsBabyM1.baking.forge: No slot found at level 836238 (max_priority = 64)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those logs simply mean your baker did not have rights at the corresponding blocks. They are not an indication that anything is wrong at that moment.